# '/usr/bin/pg_restore' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog

Tags: linux-mint, configuration, postgresql

I've installed pgadmin4 through software manager in Linux Mint Tricia. Also I've installed Postgres10. But when I create a new database and try to restore newly created database. This error message is showing:

> /usr/bin/pg_restore file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog"

I dont' know how to solve this problem. For further clarification I've added the a screenshot of the error message.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention Linux Mint, which I believe uses Ubuntu packaging.

According to [the file list for the `postgresql-client-10` Ubuntu Bionic package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/postgresql-client-10/filelist), the location of that program is `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_restore`.  If you are using the Debian based Linux Mint, I think they use the same locations.

If you installed `postgresql-10` from a different location, they could have used different paths.  Update your question with where your packages come from for better responses.

You would need to make sure you have `postgresql-client-10` installed and then update the binary paths in `pgadmin` preferences so it can find `pg_restore` and the other installed binaries.

Comment: Thank you very much installing `postgresql-client-10` did the trick.